# How does Google Autofill function?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

When I have to fill out demographic and/or personal information online, Google Autofill usually assists me in filling out previously entered in data. How does Google Autofill work? Is it part of the browser or something else that has be allowed by the website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Autofill is usually a Browser-based setting. This means that the data stored in autofill would be different from Firefox to Chrome.

In Chrome, you can check these settings (and change and delete autofill entries) by going to Settings > Show Advanced Settings > Manage Autofill settings. [Here's a help article](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142893) explaining more the options in the autofill settings.

In Firefox, [you can do the same](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/control-firefox-automatically-fills-in-forms). Firefox should already learn form entries based on the first time you fill out certain fields. You can delete single entries by clicking into a text field on a webpage, hitting *down arrow* and then *delete* on the highlighted entry you'd like to delete. To delete all auto-form entires in Firefox, you'll need to clear your cached information.

Lastly, these apply across various webpages/sites, and the info is stored at the browser level. Some websites (like credit card and bank login pages) will disable the ability for the browser to autofill information, and the prevention of the autofill info is done at the website level.